# Query taking very long the first time it runs

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

My website has serious issues during peak visit times. After doing much troubleshooting I have figured out that the problem is the database.

I have this main query that runs on Index which retrieves a table of data.

on a busy day the site takes between 30 and 45 seconds to load the first time but every time after that it loads very quickly for about 5 minutes after which it slows down again and eventually the site goes down due to too much load.

I tested the query directly on the database and it performs exactly the same.

Would this be more to do with the query or the MySQL config?

It works perfectly fine with a small return result but on a busy day when the lists are very big its really slows down and kills the site.

EDIT:

Thank you for all the suggestions.

I have slightly reworked the query and did some ammendments to the DB because some of the names were not sensible.

After all your suggestions I have also modified the query to remove the Wildcard searches and also some redundant requests to a table that is no longer necessary.

Here is the Query itself:

```
SELECT g.id, g.`name`, g.scores, g.sportFK, g.`desc`, g.`date`, s.id AS streamid
       FROM games AS g
       LEFT JOIN streams AS s ON s.gameFK = g.id
             WHERE
                  (g.date >= '" . $date . "' AND g.date <= '" . $newdate . "') 
                  AND g.sportFK IN (" .  $sportfk . ") 
                  ORDER BY g.date ASC"
```

After testing this the first performance of the query is still running at 33s and every subsequent execution is running at 0.04s which sugegsts that the effect on the site will be the same when the peak time comes.

I have also prepared the requested information from `EXPLAIN`.

This is for the 'GAMES' table

[image: Games Table]

```
GAMES TABLE:

SIZE: 6MB
ROWS: 14841
TYPE: INNODB
```

This is for the 'STREAMS' table

[image: Streams Table]

```
STREAMS TABLE:

SIZE: 80MB
ROWS: 135296
TYPE: MyISAM
```

EDIT: Martin thank you for making a point about the write. This DB does get populated from another source also at quite a regular interval so there will be constant READ and WRITE operations happening. I will have to do a little more research into this.

Comment: Do you have proper indexes on your table? Don't you need to not to fetch ALL (*) the data from your table?

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` when the argument isn't a pattern? Can `prod_name` or `cat_name` contain wildcard characters?

Comment: Possible bottlenecks of this query is "LIKE", "JOIN" and sub "SELECT" - try to avoid them if it is possible

Comment: The reason probably loads quickly when you repeat it is because MySQL caches results.

Comment: You should give us the output of explain too.

Comment: Another likely bottleneck is the correlated subquery. Try a left join with a subquery instead.

Comment: Barmar is right, try to optimize your query as much as possible. And we need more details on this.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: Correlated subquery with the table products and games too do the count.. that could be slow. LEFT JOIN on games an LEFT JOIN always needs a FULL TABLE SCAN in this case it scans the table games if the table large with bad indexes or no indexes your query will be indeed slow.  Can you provide us with a schema on SQLfriddle?

Comment: I  have same problem stated in question with ms sql as well as ms access

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening is that the extra time the first time the query runs is spent compiling the query and developing the execution plan.  This stays cached for awhile and then it happens again.

The solution is to put your query into a stored procedure.

Comment: thank you I will definitely consider using Stored Procedures, i will have to do some reading about it as I do not have any experience in using them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this query has to be performance horror for every DB developer :-)

**First** time can be prolong because of query compilation and execution plan calculation. You can look at it using `EXPLAIN`.

As the behavior is repeated in 5 minutes, I would say that there should be problem with indexes itself or in missing indexes.

You should specify whether there is only **read** within the website load or there is concurrent read (using your query) along with **writes**.

**Index recalculation** come into a play once you would also perform write operations. The other possible issue is locking. Let say every 5 minutes someone write data, the query is really complex so it should lock the table(s) for write transaction and your read would wait until commit/rollback.

Note that this query is really complex and it will never be fast - I mean really fast.

- there is count on another table using index
- one join to another table with large condition - join itself is slow point
- two where clauses => two indexes
- order using another index

You see that there is couple of indexes. Write operation just lock tables and indexes and update them, you have 5 of them. Inner count is not nice too.

I would recommend better DB or domain design if you would require really good performance or define classic approach: *is read or write often?* and than redesign it.

Comment: Martin thank you for making a point about the write. This DB does get populated from another source also at quite a regular interval so there will be constant READ and WRITE operations happening. I will have to do a little more research into this. At its current state has it been improved in your opninion?

Comment: We had many troubles regarding table locking which lead us to *clone* tables. I mean we have took use-cases and define which operation blocks another and divide data into separated tables. Right now when one thread/client writes data, second is not affected at all. When I would be precise our cases is following: we got some kind of main aggregate. It can be deployed using REST to the server and server can process it. We divide tables on the level of these main aggregates, so when someone deploys one aggregate it does not block processing of another on the server side as they are different

Comment: tables. We have learned a lot of about database. It encourages me to start reading about NoSQL. The reason is that RDBMS, MS SQL in our case, does many unexpectable things or things which is hard to learn or predicate. E.g. it sometimes lock the whole table instead of index itself, sometimes does not use index even if the table contain correct definition because it just decided to do not use it. Or term like `clustered index` is topic for long winter nights. A lot of things work magic in RDBMSs.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for databases to have caching under the hood to improve performance if a query is executed multiple times.
If you want to improve performance, you may want to get an explain plan and either improve your database structure or improve your query structure.

For improving the database, check the explain plan and make sure there are no expensive operations like full text scans.
You'd likely want to see the impact that adding indexes on g.name and the joining columns for example.
Try adding indexes, seeing the cost improvements. 
Be careful in adding indexes as the slow writes and increase database size.