# Optimizing slow match against MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database

My MyISAM table has `315,000` rows.  I have a fulltext index on `product_name`.  Cardinality is 0.

```
query_cache_size = 20M
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit =  2M
```

My query is:

```
select `id`,`product_name`,`description`,`price`,`image`,`colour` 
from table 
where MATCH (`product_name`) AGAINST (:search) 
AND `price` BETWEEN :mincost 
AND :maxcost 
ORDER BY `price` ASC LIMIT :start, :limit
```

Sometimes I will try a search and it will take around 20-40 seconds, usually the first time I try or when I havnt tried a search for 10+ minutes.  Other times it will return the results in about 2 seconds or less.  Im guessing this is to do with caching?  Something similar to [Query taking very long the first time it runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321272/query-taking-very-long-the-first-time-it-runs)

Lets say my search variable was 'test', does MySQL cache the query with the variable 'test'? So that the next time I search for 'test' the results would return quickly.

Or does it cache the actual search query regardless of what the search variable is so that whatever is searched for will return quickly?

EXPLAIN:

1
SIMPLE
table
fulltext
price,FULLTEXT_product_name
FULLTEXT_product_name
0
NULL
1
Using where; Using filesort

Comment: post the EXPLAIN select `id`,`product_name`,`description`,`price`,`image`,`colour` from table where MATCH (`product_name`) AGAINST (:search) AND `price` BETWEEN :mincost AND :maxcost ORDER BY `price` ASC LIMIT :start, :limit

Comment: How familiar are you with Mysql's "EXPLAIN" syntax - you could get some good insights into how the db is actually running your query. Yes, Mysql, can cache some queries, the amount of caching is determined in the mysql conf.
One quick question - you have  setup full text indexes for your table - have you indexed the price column? 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Do you have a btree index on price? `ALTER TABLE t ADD KEY(price)`

Comment: already have a btree on price

Comment: try to first search with price and afterwards with text, so move MATCH after BETWEEN

Comment: I just ran a search and it took about 10 seconds, 2 minutes later I clicked search again and it showed the results in 1 second... Is it caching the query + search term, or the query and any search term?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `SQL_CACHE`

> select SQL_CACHE
>   `id`,`product_name`,`description`,`price`,`image`,`colour` from table
>   where MATCH (`product_name`) AGAINST (:search) AND `price` BETWEEN
>   :mincost AND :maxcost ORDER BY `price` ASC LIMIT :start, :limit

Comment: what would you recommend for these settings?  query_cache_size = 20M
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit =  2M

Comment: database is about 1.3 gb  split into tables